# Grid view row command in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, in asp.net i am using one grid view, in that i have one link button, in row command event i am binding the url to that link, when i am clicking on that it is logging out, it is coming to login page.  In row command i am writing the code like this

Response.Redirect(s, false);

where s containt the url like abc/abc_approval/xyz.aspx. it is giving particularly that url only remaing urls redirecting to their destinations.
when it comes to login page the url like this

Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fabc%2fabc_Approval%2fxyz.aspx

help me please.

Comment: So are you saying that no matter what if you click your link button in the GridView that it logs the user out?

Comment: no karl anderson, it is particularly the boave url, there are so many urls are there, when i debug the page, it is showing no error simple redirecting to login page. The url of login page after redirecting like this :  Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fabc%2fabc_Approval%2fxyz.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem the problem of `redirect`, you may have authentication failed on `abc/abc_approval/xyz.aspx` or any error could cause the redirect to login page. In web.config check the [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tag, Login page might be the default for unhandled errors. Put debugger on the suspected page to see if any error occurs.

Comment: no it is not login page adil, it is some thing "~/User/errpag.aspx"

Comment: Did you debug the page causing this?

Comment: yes, nothing error is there it is simply redirecting to login page

Comment: You mean it redirects you to desired page xyz.aspx and after executing page load it redirects you to Login page?

Comment: No Adil, when i place break poing at destination page, it is not going there, simply redirect to login page.

Comment: Can you hard code the complete url like "http://www.abc.com/dir/yourpage.aspx" in the Redirect method, just to ensure the url?

Comment: k i will try and inform you.

Comment: yes adil i place the url which is hard code, even though it is redirecting to login page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33606/discussion-between-adil-and-surya-sasidhar)

Comment: If you put this hard coded url in browser window then you will be able to see the page?

Comment: sorry adil it is my error, actually that user dont have permission to access the page.

Comment: You are welcome, That is what I said in my answer, "you may have authentication failed"